# Can't understand why Konva text do not hide

Tags: html, konvajs

I want hide and show a `Konva.text` when I drag a rect -> show text and drag end hide the text but I can't understand why when I drag end the `Konva.text` do not hide.

```js
var stage = new Konva.Stage({ container: 'container', width: 400, height: 250 });
var layer2 = new Konva.Layer(); var groupe = new Konva.Group({})

var lineV = new Konva.Rect({ x: 50, y: 50, width: 70, height: 50, draggable: true, stroke: 'black'}); groupe.add(lineV)

var info = new Konva.Text({
    text: 'info', 
    visible: false,
    stroke: '#fff', fontSize: 35, fontFamily: 'Calibri', fill: '#000',  align: 'center', name: "infoBulle"});
    layer2.add(info);

    groupe.on('dragstart', function () {
        console.log("drag")
        info.visible(true);
    });
      
    groupe.on('dragend', function () {
        console.log("drop");
        info.visible(false)
        console.log(info.isVisible());
    });

    stage.add(layer2.add(groupe))
    stage.draw();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@2.4.2/konva.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" width="400" height="250" style="border: 2px solid red;"></div>
```

Comment: Top tip - if your code all runs but the canvas appears not to have noticed a change, then check that you do layer.draw() on any layer you were expecting to have been changed.  It could be argued that a canvas lib might do this automatically but that would be very slow if you were doing a complex animation, and in a bunch of other use-cases. Conversely though, do not just throw layer.draw() and stage.draw() everywhere as this will be an overhead.

Comment: hello, thank for your help. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redraw a layer every time you update something on it. The first time you show the text update is visible, because Konva updates layer automatically on `dragmove` action.

```js
var stage = new Konva.Stage({ container: 'container', width: 400, height: 250 });
var layer2 = new Konva.Layer(); var groupe = new Konva.Group({})

var lineV = new Konva.Rect({ x: 50, y: 50, width: 70, height: 50, draggable: true, stroke: 'black'}); groupe.add(lineV)

var info = new Konva.Text({
    text: 'info', 
    visible: false,
    stroke: '#fff', fontSize: 35, fontFamily: 'Calibri', fill: '#000',  align: 'center', name: "infoBulle"});
    layer2.add(info);

    groupe.on('dragstart', function () {
        console.log("drag")
        info.visible(true);
        layer2.batchDraw();
    });
      
    groupe.on('dragend', function () {
        console.log("drop");
        info.visible(false)
        layer2.batchDraw();
        console.log(info.isVisible());
    });

    stage.add(layer2.add(groupe))
    stage.draw();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@2.4.2/konva.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" width="400" height="250" style="border: 2px solid red;"></div>
```